# Exclude specific files from visual studio search

Tags: visual-studio, search, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I'm working with Visual Studio 2013. With WebEssentials, I have created some bundles files to minimize my javascript files, and every time I do a search, my vs freezes because it searchs also in the bundles files. So if I have, e.g., the `'externalBundle.js'` and the `'myappBundle.js'`, I want to exclude them.

I've already seen the [Excluding specific files from Visual Studio search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358432/excluding-specific-files-from-visual-studio-search) and the [How to exclude designer.cs from Visual Studio file search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596337/how-to-exclude-designer-cs-from-visual-studio-file-search) posts, but they don't solve my issue. I just want to exclude two files from the search by a pattern.

**UPDATE:** I've started a new project and I'm working with Visual Studio 2015. The issue is still present because it seems the search widgets are the same as in VS2013.

Comment: i'd rather exclude entire folders. than specific files. bump on this question.

Comment: @ColacX Are you talking about the "Look in" field to search in defined folders, in the "Find and Replace" feature, right? It could be a solution, but I would need to move the files to exclude to a new folder. That would change my folder's structure. Besides I wouldn't be able to look in "Current Project" option (which is very useful for me): I would need to define the specific folders where to look for.

Comment: - You can have separate naming convention for those js files like bundle.js.excludesearch and use it in your scripts tag.

Comment: @christiansr85 are bundled files are part of the project/solution ?

Comment: @Raghavendra yes. I could exclude them from the solution and generate them in the publishing process. That would solve this specific problem. But it would be great if users could enclose their searchs excluding specific files and reducing the files where to look.

Answer (score 1):

you have following options as of now for your problem

- All Open Files
- Exclude file and search only files in solution/project

and with above two option you can always combine and apply following rule
 - Search in files ending with specific pattern or extensions

as per above discussion it looks like you are missing exclude feature in visual studio so for now you can use some tools available for free 
some links you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433993/5357992)