# Visual Studio search feature does not seem to be searching for text in CSS files

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I noticed that when using Visual Studio's 'Find in files' search feature, it does not appear to search/find text in CSS files even though the text does exist.

I can't find anything on the net regarding this issue and cannot determine even if Visual Studio allows you to search for text within CSS files.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this; Is it supposed to allow you to do this? If so, what reasons would explain why this is not working?

Comment: Check the advanced settings on your search to make sure that you're including the files you want to search and that you're not using options that would exclude the text you want to find, for example, using a regular expression search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say I haven't come across that error before. Have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795443/visual-studio-2010-find-in-files-not-finding-files), there are some potential solutions that might help.